# How to configure which emails show up in my Focused Inbox in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, inbox

Newer versions of Outlook present a "Focused" view of your inbox, that tries to sort emails that require your attention (e.g. from people you frequently correspond with) into a "Focused" inbox and emails that aren't important (e.g. email from mailing lists) in an inbox labeled "Other". On the whole, it does an okay job. However, it's far from perfect--sometimes important emails end up in my "Other" inbox, while some unimportant emails end up in my "Focused" inbox. Is there a way to configure Outlook to change what it categorizes at "Focused" and "Other"?

Answer (score 5):

If you need to fine-tune your Focused Inbox, Move to Focused and Move to Other options are available to do that. You can choose **Move to Other/Focused** if you want only the selected message moved. Choose **Always Move to Other/focused** if you want all future messages from the sender to be delivered to the **Other/Focused** tab. See Microsoft's official documentation to know more details: [Focused Inbox for Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Focused-Inbox-for-Outlook-f445ad7f-02f4-4294-a82e-71d8964e3978)