# Is it possible to fine-tune Focused vs Other in Outlook 365?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, email-filter, microsoft-outlook-365

I understand that we can toggle the destination (*Focused* vs *Other*) of emails from **a certain sender**.

For example, [How to configure which emails show up in my Focused Inbox in Outlook?](https://superuser.com/questions/1264525/how-to-configure-which-emails-show-up-in-my-focused-inbox-in-outlook)

Do we (as users) have an option to apply more granular rules? Not just based on the sender name?

Answer (score 0):

As i know, **Tenant admins** can create transport rules to direct email messages to the Focused view for all your users. These whitelists can be set up using **mail flow rules from the Admin cente**r or via **PowerShell cmdlets**. After these are set up successfully, all future messages that satisfy these mail flow rules would be delivered in the Focused tab of the Inbox on Outlook clients that support Focused Inbox.

More information: [Configure Focused Inbox for everyone in your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/setup/configure-focused-inbox?redirectSourcePath=%252farticle%252fManage-Focused-Inbox-Admin-Help-613a845c-4b71-41de-b331-acdcf5b6625d&view=o365-worldwide#use-the-ui-to-create-a-transport-rule-to-direct-email-messages-to-the-focused-view-for-all-your-users).

Comment: I have clarified in my question that be "us" I meant end users (not admins).

Comment: If so, I'm afraid that there's no such an option or anything else can be set in Outlook to achieve your requirement.